# A Question on Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading algebraic topology by Artin, and he gives the following definition.  Let $X$ be a topological space.  We define a homomorphism $sd_X: S_p(X) \to S_p(X)$ by induction.  If $T: \Delta_0 \to X$ is a singular 0-simplex, we define $sd_XT = T$.  Now suppose $sd_X$ is defined in dimensions less than $p$.  If $i_p: \Delta_p \to \Delta_p$ is the identity map, let $\hat{\Delta}_p$ denote the barycenter of $\Delta_p$ and define $sd_{\Delta_p}i_p = (-1)^p[sd_{\Delta_p}(\partial i_p), \hat{\Delta}_p]$.  Then define $sd_XT = T_\#(sd_{\Delta_p} i_p)$.

I would appreciate it if someone could compute $T_\#(sd_{\Delta_1} i_p)(1/4, 1/4)$ explicitly.  Thank you

Comment: No I posted that one.  I just for the life of me can not figure out how to compute even this simple example.  I have spent at least ten hours trying to compute this.

Comment: Ahhhhh!!!!!!!  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: This actually isn't a duplicate though...

Comment: But the first part is very similar